# How to retrieve Trezor wallet with recovery seed?

Tags: wallet-recovery, trezor

I've been at this for days now without finding the links to click on.  I have a Trezor wallet that I bought years ago.  It has some bitcoins on it.  I have the recovery seed, but I lost the pin.  From the instructions I understand that I needed to wipe the wallet before I could start the recovery seed process.  I wiped the wallet, but cannot find the proper links to click on in the active wallet window in order to recover the bitcoins from the old seed.  I have spent a lot of time reading all the advise, but still cannot find where to click.  Please Advise, Thank You.

Comment: To state it more simply, Where is the Trezor Recovery Button?  I cannot find it anywhere on the mytrezor.com page, with my device plugged in, or not.  Either way they have not provided the Recovery process that I can find, after a great deal of searching.

Answer (score 0):

Instructions for recovering Trezors can be found on Satoshi Labs' documentation site here: https://doc.satoshilabs.com/trezor-user/recovery.html